# how do I get more than the ID to show up in a serialization of a related field

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework

My models:
//custom user class

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique = True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, )
    private_account = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    dob = models.DateField(max_length=8, null=True)
    profilepic 

//each user has a Friendslist
class Friendslist(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique = True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        CustomUser, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='friendslist')
    friends = models.ManyToManyField(
        CustomUser, related_name='friends', symmetrical=False)




class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
           
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields= ['id','bio', 'profilepic', 'friends',  'private_account', ]
        depth: 3
```

currently i get:
...friends: [a228b0f-452f-4e46-a08b-e8fd01aaf78, e1d6237-5bd4-41eb-b925-8f0b1dc885], private_account: false, ....

but I want a specific User to show up instead of the users ID. how do i go about doing this?

Comment: I find the modeling of a `FriendsList` quite odd, especially since a `User` can only have one such list. In that case it makes more sense to define a `ManyToManyField` in the `CustomUser` to itself.

Comment: hmm that does make more sense. thanks for the feedback!